What does the crankcase breather do?
I have seen multiple Honda motorcycles list "crankcase breather" cleaning as a regular maintenance item. It involves just emptying out the oil collected in a small reservoir tied to a hose. I know, if one does not do this, one starts having oil in their air filter. My question is, what exactly is happening here? How does oil travel there?


The crankcase breather does exactly what the name implies ... allows the crankcase to breath. During the combustion process, some amount of combustion gasses bypass the piston rings (the amount varies by different engine types and ring construction) and gets into the crankcase. If the breather was not present, pressure would build over time and would need to go somewhere. Since it would take the path of least resistance, it would push out through seals or by other soft parts like gaskets. Instead we have the breather, which allows them easy egress. The problem with this system is, when the gasses escape, they often take oil with them. While the engine is running, some amount of he oil in the crankcase becomes aeresolized (or a mist, if you will) and can easily travel along with the exiting gasses. Mind you it isn't a lot of oil at any given time, but it does add up. This is the build up you see when cleaning the breather.
